# Flutter Real Time Timeline Progress

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to build an app with a real timeline progress, so when its 10.00 am for example, the progress will be in the 10.00 am activity. Anyone knows what to use?

**Using Stepper Class**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScheduleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScheduleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScheduleScreenState createState() => _ScheduleScreenState();
}

class _ScheduleScreenState extends State<ScheduleScreen> {
  int _currentStep = 0;
  String time = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stepper(
          steps: _mySteps(),
          currentStep: this._currentStep,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _currentStep += 1;
      });
      //mytimer.cancel() //to terminate this timer
    });
    print('a');
    super.initState();
  }

  List<Step> _mySteps() {
    List<Step> _steps = [
      Step(
        title: Text('Step 1'),
        content: Text('Step 1'),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Step 2'),
        content: Text('Step 2'),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 1,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Step 3'),
        content: Text('Step 3'),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 2,
      )
    ];
    return _steps;
  }
}
```

So the code there is basically me adding steps per second.

Comment: Provide code, please. It's possible using Column and Stack. The bottom widget of Stack will be a Column with all times node and the exact same height of each widget. And top will be another Column but the height will be calculated using the current time. This is just one way to implement.

Comment: @pavel_birdy Hi, I'm using Stepper, I'll edit the question.